# Responsive design and min-width in pixels

Tags: html, css, width, responsive-design

I'm learning the new "Responsive design", and one of the first things I understood is that we should use percentages in defining whatever we could define, most importantly, the `width`.

Let's say I have 2 `inline-block` divs.

```
<div>
   //Left div
</div>
<div>
   //Right div
</div>
```

The first div, has a `width:50%`, the second div has a `width:40%`, everything seems good here, they are beside each other, and when you resize the browser they will get smaller.

So that we stop them from resizing too much (where things become unreadable), we should use `min-width` in pixels.

If I set `min-width:200px;` for the first div, and `min-width:100px;` for the second div, and when I resize the window until the second div becomes under the first div, everything seems good.

But if I resize MORE and MORE, the `width` will stay fixed because the browser size is less than the `min-width` of those divs, which will lead to the creation of the scrollbar.

I am resizing so I can test how things should look on smaller resolutions (phones, tablets), am I missing something here? Is this where everything stops and the role of media queries begin? or there's more that I can do to fix this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MxtT/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demo the problem you are having.  Not all responsive layouts are based on percentage widths.

Comment: @Lowkase I provided one.

Comment: If you believe that media queries might be the key here, why didn't you try them?  If you did try them, was there a reason they didn't work for your layout?

Comment: @cimmanon I have just learning this "Responsive design" and I was just wandering if there's anything yet to do before using queries, there's no problem with using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this where everything stops and the role of media queries begin?

Essentially, yes. Media Queries are what you need to use when you feel that your design can no longer squeeze in to the space you're providing it. At the point you're talking about, roughly 300px window size (plus margins?) you would want to use a media query to change the way you display those divs, perhaps so that they were 100% of the width of the viewport, and thus stacked one on top of another rather than side by side. This would effectively over-ride the min-width in practical terms for your example.

What you want to achieve is a design that works regardless of the viewport size, and the moment that making the viewport too small, or too big, means that the layout is hard for the user to use or read, then media queries provide the best way right now to "reset" the layout to re-inject usability for that new set of dimensions.

I would say you don't necessarily have to worry about setting a min-width; though there's a strong argument for using them to take in to consideration internet explorer, as it won't deal with media queries in it's older versions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is known as responsive layout.

Here are couple of reference links that might help you to achieve responsive layout.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

http://www.elementfusion.com/tutorial-optimizing-your-website-for-mobile-devices

Comment: I would advise you strongly disregard this kind of practice. Use media queries to change the layout when the layout can no longer hold your content in a usable manner, don't set pre-defined "device" break points. Doing it in this manner, rather than with device break points, keeps everything future-proof, and means you're making your site work wherever it's displayed as standard.